# How to load multiple files in R?

Tags: r

I have three files I want to load in. They are all CSV's. I want to load all three files all at once into one combined dataframe. I want to do this so I don't have to go through three lines of loading in the files separately and then an additional line binding them all. I also want to save room in my Global Environment and having three dataframes loaded when I will combine them all into one will just take up room and make things confusing. I can click and view each dataframe separately but they aren't merged like I wanted them to be. How can I load in the files at once and merge them without reading each file one after another?

Comment: I think what you need is `result <- do.call(rbind, preKSADS_all)` to combine data into one dataframe.

Comment: @RonakShah This works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `purrr::map_dfr()`:

```
files <-  purrr::map_dfr(filelist, read.csv)
```

(All data frames have the same columns as my understanding.)

Comment: Yeah, they all have the same columns. This solution should work. Thank you much!